# Angular2 RC5 infinite loop with templateUrl

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a problem with Angular2 RC5.

My app.component (which is bootstrapped by the app.module) looks like this, very basic:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: `TEST`
})

export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

    constructor() {
        console.log("APP LOG!");
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        console.log("APP INIT LOG!");
    }

}
```

As long as I code the template inside the component it works fine. But when I transfer it into its own html file and include it via

```
templateUrl: 'app.component.html'
```

I run into an infinite loop. The constructor is called over and over again, never reaching the ngOnInit. No difference whether I try relative or absolute path.
Didnt't have this issue on RC4 without ngModules.

The corresponding ngModule, also very basic:

```
@NgModule({
imports: [
    BrowserModule
],
declarations: [
    AppComponent
],
bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

I use Meteor, so everything is compiled using the Meteor angular2-compiler.

Any hints are highly appreciated!

Comment: can you show the `@NgModule()` code?

Comment: Of course, I added the code. Thx!

Comment: that `app.component.html` is located next to that `app.component.ts`? if you place the `templateUrl: 'app.component.html'` into the decorator, the `template: ''` was removed, right? :)

Comment: yes to both questions :)

Comment: Added info about compilation (I use Meteor)

Comment: you are missing `moduleId: module.id` in @Component metadata.

Comment: thx, but I also tried it with absolute path and get the same issue

Comment: What is the content of `app.component.html`

Comment: Just a sample text ("hi" in this case :))

Comment: Did you try a template with an html tag?

Comment: I was having a big headache with loops when using templateUrl. End up finding out it was due to one of my templates having a tag <example> that was conflicting with a tag implemented by angular in a component. Thought it could be useful to inform.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know that Meteor compiler, but taking a look at the documentation:
https://www.angular-meteor.com/tutorials/socially/angular2/dynamic-template

Example-Code: https://github.com/Urigo/meteor-angular2.0-socially/archive/step_01.zip

Tells us to use it like this:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

import template from './app.component.html';

@Component({
  selector: 'app',
  template
})
export class AppComponent {}
```

Comment: Yep tried that import notation as well with the same result....the strange thing is, that it doesn't throw an error but rather loop and reconstruct the component over and over again without ever entering the onInit hook. It must have to do with the fact that the template is not found or can't be imported.

Comment: Tried that downloadable sample?

Comment: Yes that sample is running but it it uses Angular2 RC4 without NgModules...